# codeigniter and the use of multi index in where(array) function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When i use this in codeigniter it only selects the last array index

```
$array = array("status !=" => "deleted", "status !=" => "concept");
$this->db->where($array);
```

this is the result:

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) WHERE `status` != 'concept'
```

Anyone knows why or knows a better way?

Comment: This piece of code should select every row for which `status` is not equals to `deleted` or `concept`. Is this what you want? Is this what you get?

Comment: @joseph Updated my post. The goal is to have `WHERE status != deleted AND status != concept`

Comment: I ran it, and got this: `SELECT * FROM (\`table\`) WHERE \`status\` != 'deleted' AND \`status\` != 'concept'`

Comment: What do you get when you run this: `$this->db->where(array("sta\`tus !=" => "deleted", "status !=" => "concept"))->get('table');`? You should get an error (since I added an extra backtick there), but it should display the query it's trying to run...

Comment: found the problem! when i make the second array index that is the same as the previous one it will override the old one! Very normal behavior of an array off course.

Comment: Have to wait 7 hours to answer my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already figured out the reason for this on your own (you're simply overriding the array key), you should use one of the following options:

You can either pass it all in as a string in the first argument:

```
$this->db->where("status != deleted AND status != concept")->get('table');
```

Or you can make 2 separate method calls:

```
$this->db->where("status !=", "deleted")
         ->where("status !=", "concept")
         ->get('table');
```

The first one is simpler, but the second one is safer.

Comment: Well the setting of the array doesn't happen inside the model it self! I get the where array from a config file that sets different where array's for different conditions. The first one i think i will go with! i can make the where array in the config a string and it will still work! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it should work, alternatively you can try this:

```
$array = array("status !=" => "deleted", "status !=" => "concept");
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $this->db->where($k,$v);
}
```

Comment: There is no need for this. The OP's way is the correct one. Read the docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html . Go down to `$this->db->where();`, and take a look at method number 3.

Comment: that is an option i considered but i find it odd that it won't work the way i wrote it. strange. Guess i would do it your way

Comment: Yes @Joseph Silber, but Mark says he does not work ... There are a couple of things that can be, and is best to try that theorizing ...

Answer (score 0):

If the column is the same for all clauses, a better/cleaner choice than multiple `where()`s  would be the [`where_not_in()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) method.
It does just what it says - creates a `NOT IN (..)` clause

Sample usage:

```
$this->db->where_not_in('status', $bad_statuses);
```